# Inserting an image after text in pdf using iText7

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

I'm making a simple program with .NET and iText7
Inserting a signature image in a PDF document is one of the functions under production.

It has been implemented until the image is inserted into the PDF and newly saved, but I don't know if the image goes behind the text.

The Canvas function seems to be possible, but no matter how many times I look at the example, I can't see any parameters related to the placement.

It would be nice to present a keyword that can implement the function.

The sample results are attached to help understanding. In the figure, the left is the capture of the PDF in which I inserted my signature using a word processor, and the right is the capture of the PDF generated through IText.

My iText version is .Net 7.2.1.
I attached the code below just in case it was necessary.

Thank you.

```
public void PDF_SIGN(FileInfo old_fi)
{
    string currentPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
    String imageFile = currentPath + "\\sign.jpg";
    ImageData data = ImageDataFactory.Create(imageFile);

    string source = old_fi.FullName;
    string sourceFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(source);
    string sourceFileExtenstion = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(source);
    string dest = old_fi.DirectoryName + "\\" + sourceFileName + "(signed)" + sourceFileExtenstion;

    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(source), new PdfWriter(dest));
    Document document = new Document(pdfDoc);

    iText.Layout.Element.Image image = new iText.Layout.Element.Image(data);
    image.ScaleAbsolute(Xsize, Ysize);
    image.SetFixedPosition(1, Xaxis, Yaxis);

    document.Add(image);

    document.Close();
    pdfDoc.Close();
}
```

Sample Result (Left: Gaol, Right: Current result):

[image: Sample Result (Left: Gaol, Right: Current result)]

Comment: Well, you set a fixed image position (`image.SetFixedPosition(1, Xaxis, Yaxis)`), so _obviously_ iText won't try to position it somewhere else than at that fixed position... That being said, I don't see you adding any text after which that image should go. Or do you mean it should go somewhere after the existing content of the source file?

Comment: @mkl I think my explanation was insufficient. In order to explain my situation, a sample result capture was added to the body. thanks for your reply.

Comment: So in essence you want to know how to look for a specific piece of text in a PDF - here "Kang Jin Hyeok (Sign)" - and replace that "(Sign)" text by an image?

Comment: @mkl I don't want to replace it, but I want to overlap the text and the image like a capture on the left. The left capture is the result I want, and the right capture is in the current state.

Comment: Ah, ok, I confused _goal_ and _current result_.

Answer (score 0):

You can organize content you add using iText in the same pass before or behind each other simply by the order of adding, and layout elements may have background images or colors.

The previously existing content of the source document, consequentially, usually serves as a mere background of everything new. Except, that is, if you draw to a page in a content stream that precedes earlier content.

Unfortunately you cannot use the `Document` class for this as its renderer automatically works in the foreground. But you can use the `Canvas` class here; this class only works on a single object (e.g. a single page) but it can be initialized in a far more flexible way.

In your case, therefore, replace

```
Document document = new Document(pdfDoc);

iText.Layout.Element.Image image = new iText.Layout.Element.Image(data);
image.ScaleAbsolute(Xsize, Ysize);
image.SetFixedPosition(1, Xaxis, Yaxis);

document.Add(image);

document.Close();
```

by

```
iText.Layout.Element.Image image = new iText.Layout.Element.Image(data);
image.ScaleAbsolute(Xsize, Ysize);
image.SetFixedPosition(1, Xaxis, Yaxis);

PdfPage pdfPage = pdfDoc.GetFirstPage();
PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(pdfPage.NewContentStreamBefore(), pdfPage.GetResources(), pdfDoc);
using (Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdfPage.GetCropBox()))
{
    canvas.Add(image);
}
```

and you should get the desired result.

(Actually I tested that using Java and ported it to C# in writing this answer. I hope it's ported all right.)

---

As an aside, if you only want to put an image on the page, you don't really need the `Canvas`, you can directly use one of the `AddImage*` methods of `PdfCanvas`. For multiple elements to be automatically arranged, though, using the `Canvas` is a good idea.

Also I said above that you cannot use `Document` here. Actually you can if you replace the document renderer that class uses. For the task at hand that would have been an overkill, though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I tried .NewContentStreambefore(), sign image is not appear. However, I got idea from your code. I changed sign image background from white to transparent. It finally work both my and your code(with .NewCotentStreamAfter). Thanks for your answer again.

Comment: *"When I tried .NewContentStreambefore(), sign image is not appear"* - that would mean that it was hidden behind something. This is possible even if you are not aware of anything else there because some PDF generators start by first filling the page area with white even though white already is the default background.

Comment: I think you're right, too. This is because the placement order should have been adjusted when placing images through the word process. Anyway, it was possible to solve, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you save your image from .jpg to .png and remove the white background, make it transparent (only the pen stroke remains), you will see the text behind the signature.